# Node.js Callbacks in Nested Async.Waterfall() functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, nested

I'm trying to run a named function that uses async.waterfall(), within another function that uses async.waterfall().

How should the callbacks be structured, so that the output of the inner function is passed to the outer function?

The following code doesn't use nested async's and works fine:

```
//nested_async_1.js

var async = require("async");

console.log("Script running");

// Inner function, to be called by the outer function
var InnerAsync = function(callback_inner_async) {

    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            console.log("Inner function 1");
            callback(null, "results 1")
        },

        function (input_1, callback){
            console.log("function 2 " + input_1);
            callback(null, "results 2")
        }
    ],
    function (err, final_result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Server error: ", err);
            callback(err)
        }
        else{
            var return_val = "Final result " + final_result;
            console.log(return_val);
            callback_inner_async(return_val);
        }
    });
};


// Outer function
InnerAsync(function(result){
    console.log("Outer function " + result);
});
```

**Output**

```
C:\Data\>node nested_async_1.js  
Script running  
Inner function 1  
function 2 results 1  
Final result results 2  
Outer function Final result results 2
```

While the following nested async code doesn't run:

```
//nested_async_2.js

var async = require("async");

console.log("Script running");

// Inner function, to be called by the outer function
var InnerAsync = function(callback_inner_async) {

    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            console.log("Inner function 1");
            callback(null, "results 1")
        },

        function (input_1, callback){
            console.log("function 2 " + input_1);
            callback(null, "results 2")
        }
    ],
    function (err, final_result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Server error: ", err);
            callback(err)
        }
        else{
            var return_val = "Final result " + final_result;
            console.log(return_val);
            callback_inner_async(return_val);
        }
    });
};

// Outer function, which calls the inner function
async.waterfall([
    function(callback_outer){
        console.log("Outer function 1");
        callback_outer(null, "Outer result 1")
    },
    function(input_1, callback_outer){
        console.log("Outer function 2");
        // Run the inner function, and get the results
        // How should this be structured???
        callback_outer(null, InnerAsync())
    }
],
    function(err, final_outer_result){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error on outer function: " + err)
        }
        else {
            console.log("Final outer function");
            console.log(final_outer_result);
        }
    }
);
```

**Output**

C:\Data>node nested_async_2.js
Script running
Outer function 1
Outer function 2
Inner function 1
function 2 results 1
Final outer function
undefined
Final result results 2
C:\Data\nested_async_2.js:31
            callback_inner_async(return_val);
            ^

TypeError: callback_inner_async is not a function
    at C:\Data\nested_async_2.js:31:13
    at C:\Data\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Data\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:1201:34)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:374:17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
function(input_1, callback_outer){
    console.log("Outer function 2");
    // Run the inner function, and get the results
    // How should this be structured???
    callback_outer(null, InnerAsync())
}
```

it should be

```
function(input_1, callback_outer){
    console.log("Outer function 2");
    InnerAsync(function(result) {
        console.log("Result from InnerAsync: ", result);
        callback_outer(null, result);
    });
}
```

to work as expected. In your `nested_async_2.js`, you call `InnerAsync` without a callback, so it fails when trying to call it.

Also there are couple of issues with error handling in `InnerAsync`. That function doesn't follow `error-first callback` pattern and as a related thing, the code will fail on these lines

```
function (err, final_result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Server error: ", err);
        callback(err) // will fail here
    }
```

(if an error occurs), because `callback` is not defined there.

Comment: Works perfectly - Thanks @svlapin

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the **InnerAsync**  without any argument;
so while calling the **InnerAsync** you are not passing the callback function **callback_inner_async** that by you are getting the error.

try this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback_outer){
        console.log("Outer function 1");
        callback_outer(null, "Outer result 1")
    },
    function(input_1, callback_outer){
        console.log("Outer function 2");

        // Call InnerAsync with the callback function

        InnerAsync(callback_outer);
    }
],
    function(err, final_outer_result){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error on outer function: " + err)
        }
        else {
            console.log("Final outer function");
            console.log(final_outer_result);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Won't work, because `InnerAsync` calls its callback passing the result of successful execution as a first parameter, while `async` expects to get an error object. So it will be treated like a failed `waterfall` chain.